# Silex url generator: Unable to generate

Tags: url, generator, silex

I'm using the Silex url generator to name my routes. But the retrieval of them doesn't seem to work in different files.

I include them first:

```php
include __DIR__ . '/app/pages/bootstrap.php';
include __DIR__ . '/app/news/bootstrap.php';
```

In the pages bootstrap I have:

```php
$app->get('/admin/pages', function(Request $request) use($app){
   // code
})->bind('admin.pages.index');

echo $app['url_generator']->generate('admin.pages.index');
```

And in the news bootstrap I have:

```php
$app->get('/admin/news', function(Request $request) use($app){
   // code
})->bind('admin.news.index');

echo $app['url_generator']->generate('admin.news.index');
```

It generates 'admin.pages.index' perfeclty, but for 'admin.news.index' I receive:

```php
'Unable to generate a URL for the named route "admin.news.index" as such route does not exist.'
```

**Observations**

• When I put everything in one file, it works fine.

• When I change the load order to:

```php
include __DIR__ . '/app/news/bootstrap.php';
include __DIR__ . '/app/pages/bootstrap.php';
```

It generates 'admin.news.index' fine, but 'admin.pages.index' fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When having the code in 2 files with the code you posted, this is what happens:

1. A route is declared (“admin.pages.index”)
2. You use the UrlGenerator, thus calling its constructor, **which takes the routes as argument**.
3. Another route is declared (”admin.news.index”)
4. You use the UrlGenerator again, but this time the same instance is returned.

In other words: **all** routes are expected to be defined before you use the UrlGenerator for the 1st time.

Having said that, I wouldn’t know why it should work if you have everything in one file, except that I’d guess in that case, you had a block of route declarations and after that a block with the 2 UrlGenerator method calls.

Comment: I understand the source of the problem now. I'll modify my code so all route names are binded first. Thank you very much for your excellent explanation.

Comment: By the way: putting the controller code in real controllers is a much better way to organized the controller code. Just search the web for examples and blog posts.

Comment: I do have real controllers but I simplified the code a bit for stackoverflow, as they suggest minimal code examples (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).